# Moen bathroom faucet handle removal

Tags: plumbing, water, faucet, sink, stuck

I have a moen faucet handle that has been hard to turn and I suspect some kind of build-up. Anyway, I tried to remove the handle, and from my research, it seems I have to turn the base but it is really hard to turn. I tried WD-40 and a strap wrench but couldn't get it to turn and don't want to scratch it.

I figured I might have to remove the base altogether but I am still puzzled about how to take this out and don't want to start dismantling anything I can't put back together. There is no visible screw anywhere on the model. I have attached pictures below. How do I unturn this to clean the handle/base of the handle?

[image: Faucet]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Usually with water, vinegar or a calcium remover is more helpful than WD-40 for build up.

Comment: Yes I was planning on cleaning the handle part with that, I wasn't expecting the base to be stuck like that as well so I just used that to loosen it up - do you suggest soaking the area, or even the entire faucet in remover or water/vinegar mixture? I don't want to damage any rubber gaskets or the finish

Comment: A few(5) minutes soak should be okay, a few hours might be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a closer look, it appears you have to pull on the wire marked #1.

That should unlock the #2 and #3 (not shown), allowing you to pull the valve assembly while exposing the valve inner. From there you can proceed with disassembly.

[image: valve]